# How get UIImage from PDF

Tags: ios, pdf, uiimage

Url for me to get pdf. I need like a 4 page pdf file to get UIImage, but not all of it, but only part of the page. Please tell me how to make this easier. Thanks for the time spent[image: Exapmle]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this framework to convert UIImage to PDF.

https://github.com/mindbrix/UIImage-PDF

Answer (score 6):

Stefan Kieleithner has written a blog post called [Extracting Images from a PDF in Swift](https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2019/extracting-images-from-a-pdf-in-swift/) that shows how to extract images from a PDF page. The following code is an implementation of the presented code inside a Swift 5 / iOS 12 Playground page:

```
import Foundation
import PDFKit
import MobileCoreServices

func getEmbeddedImages(in pdfPage: PDFPage) -> [UIImage] {
    guard let cgPDFPage = pdfPage.pageRef, let dictionary = cgPDFPage.dictionary else {
        print("Couldn't open page.")
        return []
    }
    var res: CGPDFDictionaryRef?
    guard CGPDFDictionaryGetDictionary(dictionary, "Resources", &res), let resources = res else {
        print("Couldn't get Resources.")
        return []
    }
    var xObj: CGPDFDictionaryRef?
    guard CGPDFDictionaryGetDictionary(resources, "XObject", &xObj), let xObject = xObj else {
        print("Couldn't load page XObject.")
        return []
    }

    //Enumerate all of the keys in `dict', calling the block-function `block' once for each key/value pair.
    var imageKeys = [String]()
    CGPDFDictionaryApplyBlock(xObject, { key, object, _ in
        var stream: CGPDFStreamRef?
        guard CGPDFObjectGetValue(object, .stream, &stream),
            let objectStream = stream,
            let streamDictionary = CGPDFStreamGetDictionary(objectStream) else {
                return true
        }

        var subtype: UnsafePointer<Int8>?
        guard CGPDFDictionaryGetName(streamDictionary, "Subtype", &subtype), let subtypeName = subtype else {
            return true
        }

        if String(cString: subtypeName) == "Image" {
            imageKeys.append(String(cString: key))
        }
        return true
    }, nil)

    let allPageImages = imageKeys.compactMap { imageKey -> UIImage? in
        var stream: CGPDFStreamRef?
        guard CGPDFDictionaryGetStream(xObject, imageKey, &stream), let imageStream = stream else {
            print("Couldn't get image stream.")
            return nil
        }
        var format: CGPDFDataFormat = .raw
        guard let data = CGPDFStreamCopyData(imageStream, &format) else {
            print("Couldn't convert image stream to data.")
            return nil
        }
        guard let image = UIImage(data: data as Data) else {
            print("Couldn't convert image data to image.")
            return nil
        }
        return image
    }

    return allPageImages
}
```

Usage:

```
let fileUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "File", withExtension: "pdf")!
let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url: fileUrl)!
let pdfPage = pdfDocument.page(at: 0)!
let images = getEmbeddedImages(in: pdfPage)
print(images)
```

Comment: I did try you code 
in playground 

I did print `data` , and there is data.

but I get this error 
`Couldn't convert image data to image`