# iOS pdf with image encoded as ccitt

Tags: c#, ios, swift, xamarin

Do anyone have experience with PDF's which has images encoded as ccitt.
I use Xamarin, almost all pdf's seems to work. But this encoding seems a struggle. The app is for iOS.
The page size is correct but fully blank.

```
var pageRect = _page.GetBoxRect(CGPDFBox.Media);
pageRect.Size = new CGSize(pageRect.Size.Width, pageRect.Size.Height);
//pageRect.Origin = CGPointZero;

UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(pageRect.Size);
CGContext context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();

//White BG
context.SetFillColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
context.FillRect(pageRect);
context.SaveState();

// Next 3 lines makes the rotations so that the page look in the right direction
context.TranslateCTM(0.0f, pageRect.Size.Height);
context.ScaleCTM(1.0f, -1.0f);
CGAffineTransform transform = _page.GetDrawingTransform(CGPDFBox.Media, pageRect, 0, true);
context.ConcatCTM(transform);

context.DrawPDFPage(_page);
context.RestoreState();

UIImage img = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphics.EndImageContext();

return img;
```

_page is the `CGPDFPage` object.

Or do anyone have a snippet for getting images from a PDF file?
The DrawPDFPage is I think the problem which cant handle this pdf.
Snippets in swift or c are no problem

**Update**
I use in my application by default `CATiledLayer`. This will render the pdf in parts (tiles) so big pdfs will show parts instead waiting for a long time.
I found out that when encoding is set, the code above will work because it renders the full pdf first and then show on screen.

The [CATiledLayer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/catiledlayer) in that case not working and shows the empty / blank page.
My search will now be to looking for a way that the [CGPDFDocument](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgpdfdocument) or [CGPDFPage](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgpdfdocument/cgpdfpage) will return my the metadata so I am able to view the encoding.
Anyone already experience with?

Comment: Try this [tool](https://github.com/mindbrix/UIImage-PDF) to help you create image, and this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47948351/8187800) maybe also helpful.

Comment: @ColeXia-MSFT thanks for your suggestion. However this wont work because it does the same as above. The drawing of the full page at once works correct with encoding, but not in parts (tiles). Do you know how I can get the metadata of a pdf-page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time of debugging I found the solution.
CTM is already done in the ConcatCTM
What exactly is I have no idea, this is my result:

```
// fill with white background
context.SetFillColor(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);
context.FillRect(Bounds);
context.SaveState();

var pageRect = _page.GetBoxRect(CGPDFBox.Media);
context.TranslateCTM(0, Bounds.Height);
context.ScaleCTM(1, -1);

//get the affine transform that defines where the PDF is drawn
var affineTransform = _page.GetDrawingTransform(CGPDFBox.Media, layer.Bounds, 0, true);
//concatenate the pdf transform with the CTM for display in the view
context.ConcatCTM(affineTransform);

context.DrawPDFPage(_page);
context.RestoreState();
```